# what's wrong with this prime generator?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i am a newbie to C++. i just can't figure out what is going wrong with this code.
the code goes here:

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    cout<<"Enter number of digits to be tested: ";
    cin>>a;
    if (a==2)
    {cout<<a<<" is a prime number."<<endl;}
    else
    {
        cout<<"2 is a prime number."<<endl;
        for (b=3; b<=a; b++)
        {
            for (c=2; c<=b; c++)
            {
                d=b%c;
                if (d==0)
                {break;}
                else 
                {cout<<b<<" is a prime number."<<endl;}
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output for a=11 is like

```
2 is a prime number.
3 is a ...
5 is a ...
5 ...
5 ...
7 ...
7 ...
7 ...
7 ...
7 ...
9 ...
11 ...
11 ...
11 ...
11 ...
11 ...
11 ...
11 ...
11 ...
11 ...
```

i'll be thankful for help.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?  Or have you tried adding more `cout` statements to track what your code is doing?

Comment: Always fabricate your own logic before you go over the internet. Why are you so much dependent upon those examples on the internet?

Comment: if i had relied on internet examples, my code would have done what i wanted. sir lion

Answer (score 2):

The printing of `X is a prime number` needs to be moved outside the innermost loop (with an appropriate condition).

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (c=2; c<=b; c++)
```

You cannot take `c=b` case.  `c` must be less than `b`, as `b` is the number whose primality you're supposed to test, and if you take `c=b` case, then no matter what `b` is, it will be divided by `c`.